# How do I send data from Unity gear VR app over bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I am new to Unity and  android app development. I recently got hold of a Samsung gear VR and galaxy S6.

I am able to make simple scenes and run them using the gear VR. However for my project, when I am running the app on my gear VR, I would like to send data regarding the player coordinates, joystick etc over the phones Bluetooth so that it can be read on my computer in Matlab in real time.

I need this data to trigger an external device using Matlab.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Bluetooth plugins on both sides because Unity does not support this out of the box. You can write one for yourself with [Android Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) or use this cheap [one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/26661) that only cost $10.

On the computer side/Windows, you can use Winsock RFCOMM. You can get sample code [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296). Other important [links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362928(v=vs.85).aspx). Bluetooth [tutorials](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4k.html) on Windows.